# std::cin.read() fails to read stream

Tags: c++, google-chrome-extension, chrome-native-messaging

I'm implementing a [native host](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/apps/nativeMessaging/) for a browser extension. I designed my implementation around `std::cin` instead of C-style `getchar()`

The issue here is that `std::cin` not opened in binary mode and this has effects on Windows based hosts because Chrome browser don't work well with Windows style `\r\n` hence I have to read it in binary mode.

To read in binary mode, I have to use `_setmode(_fileno(stdin), _O_BINARY);`

My IDE can't find definition for `_fileno` and I found that the workaround is to use the following macro,

```
#if !defined(_fileno)
#define _fileno(__F) ((__F)->_file)
#endif
```

However, I'm not confident enough with this macro. I believe something is wrong, but I'm using the latest MinGW compiler and not sure why it's not defined.

Update: it seems the function is behind a `__STRICT_ANSI__`  and I have no idea how to disable it.

Whatever, the program compiles fine and the browser starts it, and when I send message from browser, the application able to read the length of message, and when it try to read the content, the `std::cin.read()` operation inserts nothing to the buffer vector and the message is not null terminated, but I don't think that causing the issue.

I also made an attempt to send a dummy message to browser without reading but it seems freezing the browser.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

#ifdef __WIN32
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <io.h>
#endif

#if !defined(_fileno)
#define _fileno(__F) ((__F)->_file)
#endif

enum class Platforms {
    macOS = 1,
    Windows = 2,
    Linux = 3
};

Platforms platform;

#ifdef __APPLE__
    constexpr Platforms BuildOS = Platforms::macOS;
#elif __linux__
    constexpr Platforms BuildOS = Platforms::Linux;
#elif __WIN32
    constexpr Platforms BuildOS = Platforms::Windows;
#endif


void sendMessage(std::string message) {
    auto *data = message.data();
    auto size = uint32_t(message.size());

    std::cout.write(reinterpret_cast<char *>(&size), 4);
    std::cout.write(data, size);
    std::cout.flush();
}

int main() {
    if constexpr(BuildOS == Platforms::Windows) {
        // Chrome doesn't deal well with Windows style \r\n
        _setmode(_fileno(stdin), _O_BINARY);
        _setmode(_fileno(stdout), _O_BINARY);
    }

    while(true) {
        std::uint32_t messageLength;

        // First Four contains message legnth
        std::cin.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&messageLength), 4);

        if (std::cin.eof())
        {
            break;
        }

        std::vector<char> buffer;

        // Allocate ahead
        buffer.reserve(std::size_t(messageLength) + 1);

        std::cin.read(&buffer[0], messageLength);

        std::string message(buffer.data(), buffer.size());

        sendMessage("{type: 'Hello World'}");
    } 
}
```

Comment: Have you looked into [freopen](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/freopen/)

Comment: @user4581301 Did you just delete your answer? I used it and it did work, and I was able to see the message, but still the outgoing stream fails..

Comment: I deleted answer because I needed to check a detail. I don't think it is 100% complete, though. You probably still have a problem with the stream opening in text mode, and that I don't know how to solve. Camwin's pitch of `freopen` looks like a reasonable candidate.

Comment: @user4581301 No, it opens in binary mode because of `_setmode(_fileno(stdin), _O_BINARY);`

Comment: Note: I am using msys2's build of mingw GCC 10.2  and `fileno` is in stdio.h  just like it should be in a POSIX system. As is `setmode`.

Comment: @user4581301 I just added `stdio.h` instead `<cstdio>` and I'm seeing `fileno` under `__STRICT_ANSI__`.   `__STRICT_ANSI__` set to 1 aka `true`. Is there a way to disable this?

Comment: I have no `__STRICT_ANSI__`  Instead it looks like I have `#if !defined(NO_OLDNAMES) || !defined(_POSIX)`. What version of GCC are you using? g++ -v on the command line should tell you.

Comment: @user4581301 `gcc version 11.1.0 (MinGW-W64 i686-posix-dwarf, built by Brecht Sanders)`

Comment: @user4581301 My builds are from winlibs.com

Comment: OK. I'm behind you. Not a good position to try to give advice from, and I can't afford to upgrade right now.

Comment: GCC's notes on `__STRICT_ANSI__`: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/C-Dialect-Options.html

Comment: @user4581301 Possibly VSCode  bug then as code compiles okay even without the custom macro I defined however outgoing messages are still not showing up in Chrome tho.

Comment: @user4581301 I figured it out. Turns out, I have to escape the JSON string quotes when sending messages like this, `sendMessage("{\"text\": \"Hello World\"}");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Solution:

```
buffer.reserve(std::size_t(messageLength) + 1);
```

should be

```
buffer.resize(std::size_t(messageLength) + 1);
```

or we can presize the buffer during construction with

```
std::vector<char> buffer(messageLength +1);
```

## Problem Explanation:

```
buffer.reserve(std::size_t(messageLength) + 1);
```

reserves capacity but doesn't change the size of the `vector`, so technically

```
std::cin.read(&buffer[0], messageLength);`
```

is illegal, and at

```
std::string message(buffer.data(), buffer.size());`
```

`buffer.size()` is still 0.

Comment: So, what needs to be done here to fix the issue?

Comment: Just realized that oversight. Sorry. Fixing.

Comment: The thing with `sendMessage(buffer.data());`  is that I don't send buffers and I send strings.  `sendMessage` also don't accept buffer.data().. I mean in real world,  I don't echo messages.

Comment: Wonder why. `buffer.data()` with a vector of `char` should be the same as `message.c_str()` so long as you have the terminating null in the buffer. Wonder what I'm missing.

Comment: That was my mistake when copy pasting thing to make a MVC in SO. I actually have raw string there like this `sendMessage("{type: 'Hello World'}")`. I edited the code in post..